# Javascript parse jQuery paramaters

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

I'm using a jQuery plugin which accepts a user parameter which can hold several users like:

```
$(elem).thePlugin({
  user: [{name: 'username1', image: 'image1.jpg'},
         {name: 'username2', image: 'image2.jpg'}]
});
```

But I would like to build the user parameter dynamically so that I can do something like:

```
var userparam;

$('table.user tr').each(function() {
  $name = $('td.name', this).html();
  $image = $('td.img', this).html();

  // add name and image to userparam
});

$(elem).thePlugin({
  user: userparam
});
```

How to build the userparam var?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var userparam = [];

$('table.user tr').each(function() {
  $name = $('td.name', this).html();
  $image = $('td.img', this).html();

  // add name and image to userparam
  userparam.push({ "name":$name, "image": $image });
});

$(elem).thePlugin({
  user: userparam
});
```